# pre-commit: run flake8 with python 3.6.8

Tags: python-3.6, flake8, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I installed Pyton 3.6.8 on my system.

```
python3 --version   //-> Python 3.6.8
python3.6 --version //-> Python 3.6.8
```

My pre-commit-config.yaml is:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
rev: v2.4.0
-   repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
rev: 3.7.9
hooks:
- id: flake8
  language_version: python3.6
```

I installed the pre-commit hook for my project.
Every time when I want to commit some changes to git, the pre-commit is running with the flake8 error:

```
TYP005 NamedTuple does not support defaults in 3.6.0
```

This is true for Python 3.6.0, because this feature is introduced and allowed with Python 3.6.1+. 
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

How can I configure flake8 to run with Python 3.6.8?

**EDIT**
When I run flake8 file.rb, I don`t get the error message TYP005.

```
python3 -m pip install flake
flake --version //-> 3.7.9 (the same version as in the pre-commit script file)
```

Comment: `language_version: python3.6.8`? Or is that an executable? I assume you're using https://pre-commit.com. Do you have any other flake8 config? What happens if you run it other than by pre-commit?

Comment: Yes I use pre-commit.com. If I use python3.6.8 I still get the same error. I`ve no further flake8 config files.

Comment: What if you run flake8 directly? Maybe you *should* have other config.

Comment: when I run flake8 file.rb I do not get this error message. Installed by; python3 -m pip install flake8. Furthermore flake8 --version is also 3.7.9

Comment: Please [edit] this information into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

disclaimer: I'm the author of two of the tools in question (pre-commit, flake8-typing-imports) and the maintainer of the other (flake8)

---

the TYP005 code comes from [flake8-typing-imports](https://github.com/asottile/flake8-typing-imports#flake8-codes)

there are two options for indicating your minimum supported version to `flake8-typing-imports`, the first is a command line argument / flake8 setting:

```
--min-python-version 3.6.1
```

or in your flake8 configuration

```
[flake8]
min_python_version = 3.6.1
```

---

if you're distributing a library, you can indicate the minimum supported version using the [`python_requires` metadata](https://packaging.python.org/guides/dropping-older-python-versions/#specify-the-version-ranges-for-supported-python-distributions) -- this is specified in `setup.cfg`

```
[options]
python_requires >= 3.6.1
```

---

an aside, I believe there's some information missing from your question, without `additional_dependencies` in your pre-commit configuration, `flake8` will be installed in isolation and won't have access to plugins such as `flake8-typing-imports` -- my guess is you've actually got a configuration similar to:

```yaml
-   repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 3.7.9
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
        additional_dependencies: [flake8-typing-imports==1.9.0]
```

when speaking of command line arguments above, you could specify them as `args` here (though I personally prefer the configuration file approaches)

```yaml
    -   id: flake8
        args: [--min-python-version, '3.6.1']
        additional_dependencies: [flake8-typing-imports==1.9.0]
```